# Getting Angularjs $http post response as file result

Tags: angularjs

I have a very long content request parameters form my web api. So I need send a POST request . And my api is creating a PDF file as response. But I can not get the result with angularjs $`http` provider.

```
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://myapi.com/api/renderfile',
  data: { 
       p1: 'very long text....' ,
       p2: 'another very long text....',
       p3: 'another very long text....' 
  }
}

$scope.isLoading = true;

$http(req).then(function(response){

       // response is file result how can I save it ???

       $scope.isLoading = false;
   }, function(){
       $scope.isLoading = false;
   });
```

I can not save the file response on client?

response is like this:

[image]

When I use FileReader

```
 new FileReader().readAsDataURL(new Blob([response.data], {type:'application/pdf'}));
```

The popup appears on browser:

[image]

But file is empty.

Comment: What is the response content type?

Comment: Do you really need to go through AJAX for this? I think a common approach is to return a link to a remote repo where the user can download the file and let the browser handle downloading.

Comment: What do you mean "can not get the results"? What is in the response object?What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 5):

You can force browser to download this file if you have file content in your response.

```
var reader = new FileReader();

$http(req).then(function(response){
   reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([response.data], {type:'application/pdf'}));
});

reader.onload = function(e) { 
    window.open(decodeURIComponent(reader.result), '_self', '', false); 
}
```

But preferred solution is to include `location` header in your response with the link to file. So you can force browser to download just by navigating to this link.

Proposed solution works only in HTML5 browsers.

Comment: Cool ! never thought this way .. i used to create forms when file download is required. :P

Comment: @atulquest93 Interesting. How you download with forms? I mean when you have AJAX response with file content? Could you point to some resource or source code?

Comment: @bookmarker, just refer to `response.data` when use `FileReader`. I've updated code.

Comment: I updated, but error is:   Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

Comment: Seems your data is not in correct type. Need to be convered into `Blob` => `new Blob([response.data], {type:'application/pdf'})`. I've updated example

Comment: Yes I updated post that popup appears and downloaded file is empty

Comment: No exceptions in console?

Comment: No exception in console, browser popup is appearing but content is not a pdf file. it is a raw data.

Comment: according 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response
you need add responseType:'blob'  in your req variable. otherwise you will get a faile file

Answer (score 2):

### Downloading Binary Files with AngularJS

When downloading binary files it is important to set the `responseType` attribute of the XHR.

```
var config = { responseType: 'blob' }

var httpPromise = $http.get(url, config);

httpPromise.then(function (response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
});
```

For more information, see [MDN XHR API - ResponseType.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType)

---

### Creating a <kbd>Download</kbd> Button

This is an example of a <kbd>Download</kbd> button that becomes active **after** the data is loaded from the server:

```
<a download="data_{{files[0].name}}" xd-href="data">
  <button ng-disabled="!data">Download</button>
</a>
```

The **`xdHref`** Directive

```
app.module("myApp").directive("xdHref", function() {
  return function linkFn (scope, elem, attrs) {
     scope.$watch(attrs.xdHref, function(newVal) {
       if (newVal) {
         elem.attr("href", newVal);
       }
     });
  };
});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR.](https://plnkr.co/edit/BXSuqaQff928w3SQQ170?p=preview)